# Choice of GPS receviers with API for tracking location on Google Maps (Live)

Tags: c#, api, google-maps, gps

i was wondering if anyone knows of any gps receivers that have a fairly good API..

I am hoping to develop a simple app that will show my location (live) on google maps using the google maps api but of course would need an recevier that i can interface with too whilst on the move.

Cheers.

NB: Work would be done in c#.

Comment: Is this an embedded project / robot or meant to work with a regular laptop? Does it have to be USB, etc?

Comment: it would ideally be a normal laptop with a usb gps unit attached by cable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284285/c-serial-communication-with-u-blox-gps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read data from an USB-GPS-Receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542473/read-data-from-an-usb-gps-receiver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most still provide a serial connection. Coordinates would be coming in ASCII format, and that is super-easy to process.

Comment: As referenced in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542473/read-data-from-an-usb-gps-receiver, pretty much all GPS receivers speak a standard protocol called NMEA 0183, and most USB or Bluetooth receivers show up as a virtual COM port which you can read from like a file (mostly). There are some good C# libraries already to help you parse the data too.