# Read data from an USB-GPS-Receiver

Tags: c#, .net, windows, gps

I'm wondering how difficult it is to read positioning data from an USB GPS Receiver (also known as "USB Mouse"). Is there some kind of ready-to-use API in .NET (like it is in mobile platforms like Android/WP7 etc.) which works because the GPS device's driver integrates much into Windows or is this some annyoing pinvoke stuff that depends on the GPS device?

Any experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically a GPS device shows up as a virtual com port.  You should see it listed in com ports in the device manager.  Nearly every GPS sends data to the computer using standard  [NMEA 0183](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183) messages, you just need a library to read them.  One really nice full featured one is [DotSpatial](https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial), the DotSpatial.Positioning library should automatically find your gps and report data from it.

Comment: Thank you, helped me definately

Comment: One last question: do you know some kind of a "fake gps software" that simulates that com port? Developing Indoors with a gps receiver is a little bit difficult. OS is windows 7

Comment: One thing I have done for this is to hook up your USB device to a laptop, then start up hyper terminal and open the com port of your GPS.  You should see all the NMEA messages in the window.  Drive around with it in your car for a bit, then save that data to a file.  You can then write a simple program which reads each line from your file and outputs them to another com port.  You can add two fake com ports to your computer which act as though a null modem cable was connected between them using a program such as [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/).  This works for me.

Comment: Or if you already implemented reading from your device using the DotSpatial.Positioning library, just add a record feature there.  Using fake null modem ports as I mentioned above is a good way to test it without changing your program, though.

Comment: Thanks ryan, good points. One really last question: It seems that the NMEA protocoll only delivers payload data. What if there is no satellite signal e.g. when you are indoors? Is there some overhead data that gives information about the connection or about what the *device is doing (its status)* right now? Or does it just stop sending data?

Comment: There are lots of different NMEA messages, some of which provide what they call "fix data", these list the number of satellites in range and the quality of the data you are getting (i.e. accuracy).  I believe that library I mentioned can parse those messages and give you this information as well. [This page](http://goo.gl/ksKh1) lists some of the different messages, your device may or may not have all of them. I actually have not used that library myself, I implemented my own parser, but we are looking at it for a future release to let users know the quality of the satellite signal.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to and your equipment supplier contact, and obtain recognition equipment driver, and call the API for communication equipment. If you can get from a GPS device on bytes, closer to success is just around the corner, and the rest is packaging and analytical data packets. PS: if is serial communication, realizing in DONET is more easily.