# How to connect google earth with visual studio to import real time gps data

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, gps, serial-port, google-earth

I have made a form application in C# and I need the real time gps data to be read by my form and link it to google earth where I can draw a route using the gps data.For example,i would like a button which would link to the google earth.I know we can import the real time gps data directly into google earth.But I need to access it through my application.

Comment: Here's one option how to get GPS data in C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284285/c-sharp-serial-communication-with-u-blox-gps

Answer (score 0):

A real time connection to Google Earth is possible:
Use KML Update to push out incremental updates if gps locations updates.

See [kml updates](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kml_21tutorial.html#updates)